# Opening TeX documents with TeXworks instead of TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, windows, texworks

When I open a TeX document by double-clicking on it, the LaTeX editor TeXstudio usually opens the document. I prefer using TeXworks, and I can open TeX documents using TeXworks by right-clicking and selecting "Open with". But I would prefer it if TeXworks were the "default" option for opening LaTeX documents.

Is there any way to make TeXworks the "default" program for opening TeX documents, so that TeX documents will open by default with TeXworks instead of TeXstudio?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  I presume you are on a mac.  If so go, when choosing the `Open with` option press the alt/option key and the prompt will change to `Always open with`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you for your comment. I am using a Windows HP laptop, and the technique you outlined using the "alt/option key" does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to set default program in Windows to open a `.tex`-file:

1. Goto project folder and right click on a `.tex`-file
2. Goto "Properties"
3. Under "Open With" click on <kbd>Change</kbd> (or similar)
4. Click on "Other programs"
5. Select "TeXworks" and click on <kbd>OK</kbd>

Done.

Comment: On Windows 7: (1) Right-click any `.tex` file; (2) Open with; (3) Choose another app; (4) TeXworks; (5) Check "Always use this app to open `.tex` files; (6) OK.